# Showing Progress Dialog in ArcGIS Desktop using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, geoprocessing

I have an ArcGIS custom IGPFunction tool.  I want to use the GP progress dialog not the progress bar at the bottom of the ArcGIS 10 window as I don't want people to interact with the map whilst it's processing.

In the Execute method you have an instance of ITrackCancel but I can't work out how to show the default GP progress dialog from there.  I have this as code at the moment but it still doesn't show the dialog. Any ideas?

```
        IStepProgressor pStepPro = (IStepProgressor)TrackCancel;
        pStepPro.MinRange = 0;
        pStepPro.StepValue = 1;
        pStepPro.Message = "Starting Import...";
        pStepPro.Position = 0;
        pStepPro.Show();

        ...

        pStepPro.Hide();
```

Comment: +1 - I'd like to know the answer to this, as well. Currently, I implement a backgroundworker and disable certain buttons in a winform with little way to display any sort of tool progress. When the tool can take over an hour, it would be great to show the normal progress dialog. I wonder if an answer could be extended to standalone tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is built-in to the Geoprocessing framework. If you have background processing turned on, you shouldn't block the UI. At all. It violates the principles of Geoprocessing -- what if you run the tool as a scheduled task, or in modelbuilder, or from Python?

If you absolutely HAVE to, two things:

- Pass the TrackCancel in to the [ProgressDialogFactory](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IProgressDialogFactory_Interface/0023000000st000000/).
- The [ProgressDialog](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ProgressDialogClass_Class/000v000001pz000000/) class -- use the [IProgressDialog](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IProgressDialog2_Interface/0023000000s9000000/) interface on to make visible, then use your regular StepProgressor logic on that instead.

I recommend checking if you're in a desktop application before bringing up a dialog by trying to create the [AppRef](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002300000006000000) class first -- if that fails, don't pop up a dialog.

But really, you shouldn't be second-guessing the user's preference for background/foreground processing. I'll assume in good faith you really do need this.

Comment: Yes I do need to do this. The progress dialog doesn't work for me, nothing displays.  Strangely IGPUtilities2:InApplication is returning false. Even though it's being run from ArcToolbox.

Comment: Wow, that sounds like a broken install to me.